# AlaramManager to schedule task to run after predefined time

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am trying to use `AlarmManager` to schedule a task to run at predefined time. 
This `AlarmManager` is initialized from my application and runs in background (which runs good), when the `Broadcast` event is received inside `onReceive()` method I call a service using `context.startService(webServiceIntent);` inside which I am trying to reschedule this `PendingIntent` to call say 'after 15 minutes'; but for some reasons it isn't working. All it does it it stops the `PendingIntent`.

Below are the relevant sources:

```
//Initiliazing AlarmManager from my app
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);             
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, getLocationPollerIntent(), 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),  Constant.LOCATION_POLLING_PERIOD, pendingIntent);

//onReceive Method of BroadcastReceiver
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent webServiceIntent = new Intent(context, LocationNotificationService.class);
        webServiceIntent.putExtra("UPDATED_LOCATION", loc);
    context.startService(webServiceIntent);
}

//Inside LocationNotificationService to reschedule the PendingIntent - This PendingIntent never get called

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
       c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);
       c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

       AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, getLocationPollerIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), Constant.LOCATION_POLLING_PERIOD, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem #1: `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` may have been in the past, if the millisecond ticks over during your `setRepeating()` call. Make sure you specify times in the future.

Problem #2: `13:35` may have been in the past, if you are running this code after `13:35` in the device's current time zone. Make sure you specify times in the future.

Problem #3: The device many have fallen asleep between your `startService()` call and `onHandleIntent()`, which is why I wrote [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

Comment: Yeah I get it running actually I replaced AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP with AlarmManager.RTC. But now the problem is inside wakefulIntentService this line PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, getLocationPollerIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); creates new PendingIntent instead of updating current

Comment: @Waqas: Then `getLocationPollerIntent()` is returning a different `Intent`, one that differs in more than extras.

Comment: hmm do you know if getApplicationContext() returns same/different values when called from within visible activity and when called from this wakeful intentservice? Between if it does return different values then any idea how to make this intent same for both?

Comment: @Waqas: That is not your problem. Either your action is different, your component is different, your data (`Uri`) is different, your categories are different, or your MIME type is different. See the `filterEquals()` implementation on `Intent`: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java